# Parsing JSON with undefined value

Tags: c#, json.net

How I can deserialize json in this case :

(json string I receive from server(in reality the string more and more complex) and can only change it(it's not well as I think) or customize parsing(deserializing) this string, but how do it I don't understand.....)

```
        string json = "[{\"a\":384,\"type\":undefined,\"name\":\"A\"}, {\"a\":385,\"type\":2,\"name\":\"B\"}]";
        var t = ser.Deserialize<List<CustClass>>(json);
```

"type":undefined - raise Exception " Invalid JSON primitive: undefined"

```
public class CustClass
{
    public int a{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've try using JavaScriptConverter and JavaScriptTypeResolver  but not solve the issue
may be json.net can help me? ....

Comment: Please show the declaration of `s` and the definition of `CustClass`.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid due to the unquoted `undefined` value.  This is not an allowed keyword in JSON.  See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying to avoid having things undefined if they are going to be serialized and deserialized.  Set default values.  Make sure that instead of undefined it passes in an empty string or default value.

If necessary, then I'd suggest checking first, you can do simple for loops through objects, but the easier, more efficient answer, is to not add excess.

Answer (score 0):

How is your JSON being generated? It's complaining because `undefined` is not allowed as a JSON value. The value `null` is allowed in JSON, but you need to ensure it won't cause problems when deserialized into a `CustClass` object.